# 20 most viewed "codes" with include "User" and "Language"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two tables "Codes" and "Views" and want to get a list of the 20 Codes with most views since x days ago (thats my variable dt).
Im able to get the list and sort it, but i have a problem i also would like to include 2 other tables "User" and "Language".

```
var query = from f in _db.Codes
            select new
            {
                Code = f,
                PostCount = f.ViewModels.Count(p => p.timestamp > dt)
            };

var result = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostCount).Select(y => y.Code).Take(20)
```

But after doing like this i'm not able to Include my other tables. I tried to convert the result to a ObjectQuery but then it becomes null (there are 20 Codes in the result before trying to convert it).

The Code model looks like this

```
        [Key]
    public int CodeID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Language")] 
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public LanguageModel Language { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ViewModel> ViewModels { get; set; }
```

Comment: Rephrase your question title avoiding tags and common words. Be specific, please.

Comment: How it's Related Code with User and Languages?? could you give to us your model classes or a description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
IEnumerable<CodeModel> posts = _db.Codes
    .Include("User")
    .Include("Language")
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.ViewModels.Count(p => p.timestamp > dt))
    .Take(20);
```